boton de Login/Register para google con react-native + expo
Mi problema es que cuando toco login me salta problema de Oaouth2.0 como si fuera peligroso. Sigo todos los pasos de GoogleCloud y el codigo pero no para de aparecerme eso. Funciona para Web, pero no para celular, hice la descarga del APK para probarlo por fuera, todo y sigue sin funcionar. Ya no se que pagina o video seguir porque a todos les funciona menos a mi. Alguna ayuda?

Es posible que si mostraras un poco mas sobre lo que has hecho pueda algun usuario ayudarte, inicia con parte del codigo/configuración en texto
